# Why angularJS loop rendering boxes in new row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have some products that i want to display side by side like this.
[image]

This hard coded code works fine.

```
<div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
```

But when i am trying to achieve same thing with angularJS loop.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in Products">
    <div class="box">
        //i will fill the details here.
    </div>
</div>
```

I got this result.
[image]

This is my CSS class.

```
.box {
padding : 5px;
display : inline-block;
min-width: 100px;
min-height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
```

What changes i need to do so the products can display side by side and in next row if screen width is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FIXING ORIGINAL PROBLEM**

Your `ng-repeat` should be on `<div class="box">`

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="product in Products" class="box">
        //i will fill the details here.
    </div>
</div>
```

**DESCRIPTION OF WHAT YOU WERE DOING WRONG**

By doing this you are creating repeating a new `<div class="box">` for each `product in Products`.

The way you were doing it before meant you were creating a new container element for each `product in Products`.

A simple and easy error to make.

**FIXING YOUR CSS STYLING**

To achieve the style you showed in your OP, you will want to add a margin to your repeated elements to add some spacing between them.
To do so change:

```
.box {
    padding : 5px;
    display : inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

to

```
.box {
    margin-right : 5px;
    display : inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Its works fine partially. But no padding effect getting reflected here. all elements boundaries touching to each other.

Comment: you want margins instead of padding

Comment: As @hobberwickey points out above, you will need a margin o your elements not padding.

Comment: Added some more information to the answer if it helps